# Неверная кодировка имен файлов git bash

Tags: git, git-bash

Git-2.28.0-64-bit на Windows 10.

В git bash файлы с русскими названиями выводились так

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        "\320\224\320\276\320\272\321\203\320\274\320\265\320\275\321\202.txt"
```

После установки параметра `core.quotepath=false` стали выводиться так

```
        ╨Ф╨╛╨║╤Г╨╝╨╡╨╜╤В.txt
```

При этом команда `ls` выводит все корректно

```
$ ls
Документ.txt
```

Подскажите, решение пожалуйста.

Comment: Непонятно в какой операционке не пашет? В `windows 10` команду `$ ls` - не знаю.

Comment: Это же в git bash.

Comment: Что-то вы сломали, должно работать "из коробки" всё. Нажмите ПКМ на титульнике окна, и перейдите в Options... -> Text -> Character set. Установите необходимую кодировку.

Comment: Пробовал - не помогает. По-умолчанию в настройках Local и Characture set пусто (ничего не задано). Если ставлю ru_RU:UTF-8 то результат не меняется. При KOI8-R, CP1251 и CP866 в других кракозябрах выводит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже это проблема версии v2.28.0. Поставил v2.21.0 и там все работает как надо.

Comment: You have to translate this to Russian/